# How to see OutputDebugString output in Microsoft's TestAdapterForGoogleTest in VisualStudio?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

I'm using Microsoft's TestAdapterForGoogleTest for Visual Studio. When the code ran by my Google Tests prints out something with OutputDebugString(), it is not visible in Visual Studio's Test Explorer window (while regular printouts to console with cout are visible).
I am running the test with the Test Explorer's "Debug" option.

Is it possible to present those debug strings in Test Explorer window?

Comment: This is a correct behavior. OutputDebugString() is expected to output in the debugger and not in the Test Explorer. This has nothing to do with Google Test.